# How do I rename an EV3 project?

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, programming

I can rename the program in the Home Edition software but I just can't rename a project. Please tell me how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (I use Education Edition but the menu on the Home Edition looks the same), all you need to do to rename a Project is to go to the File menu and use the "Save As" functionality to save your work under a different name. This will automatically rename the Project (as displayed on the Project tab) on your programming screen.

[image]

Comment: You can also change the "Project Title" on the Project Properties page.